# Windows Phone Offline routing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps, bing-api

I am trying to made windows phone application with offline routing. I have found that It is possible by using Bing API. 
I have registered and got the key, but I can't find, how can I use the key.

I am using following code:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RouteQuery query = new RouteQuery();

        List<GeoCoordinate> wayPoints = new List<GeoCoordinate>();

        wayPoints.Add(new GeoCoordinate(47.23449, -121.172447));
        wayPoints.Add(new GeoCoordinate(47.062638, -120.691795));

        query.Waypoints = wayPoints;
        query.QueryCompleted += geoQ_QueryCompleted;
        query.QueryAsync();
    }

    private void geoQ_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
    {
        try
        {
            Route myRoute = e.Result;
            MessageBox.Show("Completed");
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException)
        {
            /// Unauthorized access exception 0x8004231C
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // waiting for  completing the query
            geoQ_QueryCompleted(sender, e);
        }

    }
```

But I am getting Unauthorized access exception 0x8004231C.
I would like to ask you, how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bing Maps GetRoute gives '0x8004231C' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218392/bing-maps-getroute-gives-0x8004231c-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the key to show offline map. If you have map downloaded on your device, then offline routing should work. You can see the [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818495.aspx) to get more details.

Following is the quote from msdn sample,

```
However, mapping services also work without Internet connectivity when maps are downloaded for offline use.
```